# CashU payment gateway response back to return URL

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

I am integrating CashU payment gateway in my site using asp.net, c#. I want to know how to get the response back from the site on localhost after payment.

For CashU we have to give the return URL while registering with the CashU and not send it from the page. We have registered for localhost as "http://127.0.0.1:61996/ReturnPage.aspx"

But it's not returning to the return URL. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not. 127.0.0.1 is anybody's localhost address. Not sure who it'll redirect to, either the server itself or the user's machine. But definitely NOT your machine...

Comment: then how can i test it on local as i want to check what are the values return from the CashU after successful transaction by debugging.

Comment: You should provide the IP address of your machine -- assuming that if you are behind a firewall you have port forwarding.

Comment: ip address of my machine like this "http://180.236.164.135:61996/ReturnPage.aspx" how will this work ?

Comment: You'll obviously need a web server on your machine, with everything you need installed. And if you're behind a router and firewall, make sure connections to port 80 are forwarded to your machine's local IP address 10.0.x.x.

Comment: how to do this can u guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Cachu Provides two types of feedback url,one is **"Return URL"** and another one is **"Notification URL"** ,
**Return URL** is the url,where after successful transaction,the page will be redirected.
**Notification URL** is the url where,after a successful transaction,it will be informed.
After all,the url you have provided is not live url,its just a local url,that only your local machine can recognize,so make a live url,that can be recognized by the CashU server.